# jquery on (click) event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

In my page I have a textfield input (with id myname). And when I writing a name in that field, I jusing $.get to get some name-suggestion to the input. All this div objects has a class "sug". And all that data is appended in a div with the id "nameHint".

```
$("#myname).keyup(function(t){
    $.get("getname.php", {q:value}, function(data){
        nameHint.removeClass("hid").html(data); 
    }).fail(function(){nameHint.html("").addClass("hid");});
    t.preventDefault();
});
```

And the div nameHint is showed on the page. And is works perfectly.
After that when I click on one of the div, with a class sug, I want something to happend. Lets say I want to print the current div html-cod. I would used this code:

```
$("div#nameHint div.sug").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

But this on-event doesn't do enyting.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you show some of the related HTML markup?

Comment: $("#myname) => $("#myname")